# Use GooglePlay inapps with other stores

Tags: android

I'm apparently unable to find this information on the web, so i'm asking it here.

I intend on placing my app on various other stores, like Amazon and Samsung. Can I keep the billing system used already on GooglePlay or do I need to setup the billing system for each individual store using their own SDK, etc?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: you will have to use their own billing SDK/API. Amazon will simply reject your app if it contains Google Play billing.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, they have got different API's

**Samsung:**
http://developer.samsung.com/in-app-purchase

**Amazon:**
https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/in-app-purchasing